# ColdFusion 11 cfflush tag not working correctly?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Anyone having issues with the cfflush tag in ColdFusion 11? We have a routine that updates a live record count as it is processing a loop. In ColdFusion 10, this works fine. In ColdFusion 11, it waits until the end of the loop to update the screen. Not really what we expected.

Edited to add code as requested...

```
<script language="javascript">
    addOutputLine('<br /><span id="insertCount">Records Inserted: 0</span>')
</script>
<cfset insertCount = 0>
<cfset updateCountAfter = 1>
<cfif qry.recordcount gt 5000>
    <cfset updateCountAfter = 10>
</cfif>

<cfoutput query="qry" startrow="#DATASTART#">
    <!---do some stuff here that is not important to this issue--->

    <cfset insertCount = insertCount + 1>
    <cfif updateCountAfter gt 1>
        <cfif insertCount mod updateCountAfter eq 0>
            <script language="javascript">document.getElementById('insertCount').innerHTML = 'Records Inserted: #insertCount#';</script>    
        </cfif> 
    <cfelse>
         <script language="javascript">document.getElementById('insertCount').innerHTML = 'Records Inserted: #insertCount#';</script>
    </cfif>

    <cfflush>

</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Can you share some more info regarding your environment (Windows, IIS, etc)? Is this a different server than your ColdFusion 10 server (versus an in-place upgrade)?

Comment: This is our dev environment. When we upgrade the production environment, it will be the same as the dev environment - currently it is on an older box that needs to be retired. Virtual machine, Win 2012, IIS 8...all patches for CF11. CF10 was running on this environment and we did not have any issues. So..I guess this should be classed as an in-place upgrade. The number of issues with CF11 though, is killing us.

Comment: Check your `is_buffer_enable` setting in the `cfroot\config\wsconfig\1\isapi_redirect.properties` file. There is a little blurb on [Configure IIS for ColdFusion in Windows](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Installing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18a15-7ffb.html#WSf01dbd23413dda0e325f619f11fae41e1b4-7fff) that states - _change the is_buffer_enable to false in the cfroot\config\wsconfig\1\isapi_redirect.properties file. Disable webserver buffer if you want cfflush to work over an IIS connector. If your application does not use cfflush, set it to true for increase in the performance_

Comment: will have the systems guy try that! Thanks....

Comment: yahoo...rebooting both IIS AND CF after the change worked!!! Thanks so much! How do I give you credit for the right answer??

Comment: Glad that worked for you. I will create a proper answer and then you can vote it/accept it as correct so others can find it. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Promoted from the comments*

There is a configuration setting that is necessary for the `<cfflush>` tag to work properly with the web server. On the [Configuring web servers in Windows](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Installing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18a15-7ffb.html#WSf01dbd23413dda0e325f619f11fae41e1b4-7fff) documentation page, under the *Configure IIS for ColdFusion in Windows* section, among other things it states:

> To disable webserver buffer, change the `is_buffer_enable` [sic] to `false` in the cfroot\config\wsconfig\1\isapi_redirect.properties file. Disable webserver buffer if you want cfflush to work over an IIS connector. If your application does not use cfflush, set it to true for increase in the performance.

*Note that there is a typo in the Adobe documentation that I referenced above. It should state `iis_buffer_enable`, not `is_buffer_enable` (missing an 'i'). Thanks to KrunchMuffin for pointing that out.*

You will need to restart IIS for this change to take affect.

I'm not sure what the performance ramifications are of disabling this setting. You will need to do some load testing for your particular environment to see.

Comment: Just want to correct a typo, it's `iis_buffer_enable` NOT `is_buffer_enable`

Comment: @KrunchMuffin - you are correct but that is a straight quote (copy) from the Adobe documentation. I guess I should add [(sic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic) to it. Thanks.

Comment: doesn't surprise me at all. ;)